# How to read an XML file and parse it

Tags: xml, abap

I want to know how to read an xml file using ABAP, I have searched online but did not find any answers that were clear enough. Could someone kindly help me?

Thanks in advance,
Shamiron

Comment: and http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Thanks Naveed for the link......it makes a lot of sense..but in this case i was really short on time and needed some help very quick.But i do appreciate the thought.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `iXML` is an old SAP library and not so convienient to use. Please search for classes `CL_SXML_*` in transaction `SE24`. This is a new library and a lot more easier to use. You should also find something about `SXML` library easily on Google.

More about problems you can run into by using `iXML` in the SAP Note [1229110](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1229110).

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a link to the SXML documentation? SAP's own documentation has no word on it, nor do I find anything useful on the web.

Answer (score 1):

[This should get you started](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp1/helpdata/en/47/b5413acdb62f70e10000000a114084/frameset.htm). Check the "iXML ABAP Objects Jumpstart" chapter for sample code.

Comment: `iXML` is an old library. `SXML` should be used instead those days.

Comment: @Jagger, the fact that you consider it an old and not so convenient library, doesn't mean the answer is incorrect (assuming the -1 is yours).

Answer (score 0):

the method that we used was an abap transformation , in abap we can write transformations using the T-code XLST_TOOL , here we require to write some code in XML in order to convert XML to xstring and then internal table ,we also need to write a calling program. from the calling program our transformation is called.